# Confused on returning values from class methods in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to build a database constructor (factory?) in C#, however i'm confused as to how to manage errors while having "All paths return a value"

For example, here is a class that I would like to use to return a database connection:

```
public class DB
{
    static SqlConnection Connect()
    {
        SqlConnection thisConnection;

        try { 
            thisConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
        catch (SqlException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        return thisConnection;
    }
}
```

Obviously this won't work because "not all paths return a value".

How can I manage using try/catch while having a method actually return a value? Obviously i'm not a master Programmer ;) But i'm working on it.

Comment: Decide what would you like to do when the connection attempt failed, and do this in a catch block. Maybe rethrow exception, or return null, or something else

Comment: You're catching the exception, rethrow it or return null inside the catch block.

Comment: Don't catch the exception at this level if you don't have a concrete plan for how your method can successfully accomplish its mission. It sounds like you don't have such a plan, so don't catch the exception here. For logging/notifying, etc, just have a single exception handler registered at the highest level possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return `null` or re-throw exception from your catch statement. **But** it is not really a good idea to use a static connection. Rule for database connection should be **"Open as late as possible and close as early as possible"**.

You should enclose your connection in [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) that will ensure its disposal (closing) at the end of using block.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  //execute your command etc. 
}
```

Comment: It's not like he's holding onto a static connection for a while, he just created a static factory method to handle construction with some additional error handling.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for this. I'm still learning C# (Coming from more script-based languages like python and PHP). Very different approach, but I definitely already prefer it. I think. Maybe...

Answer (score 0):

an example, always returns something

```
  public bool yesno()
    {
        bool mybool = false;
        try
        {
            mybool = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            mybool = false;

        }
        return mybool;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set thisConnection=null and then return it if you are unable to instantiate an object with the given connection string. And then check for null after calling this function like

```
  If (DB.Connect("ConnectionString") != null) {
      //Connection successful
  }
  else {
     //Failed
  }


 public class DB
 {
     Static SqlConnection Connect(string connectionString)
     {
        SqlConnection thisConnection = null;

        try { 
          thisConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
        catch (SqlException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        return thisConnection;
}
```

}